# pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --alluredir

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, allure

```
(PYTEST_test_programs) E:\PYTEST_test_programs\Allure_report1>pytest test_file01.py --alluredir="C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Resumes\reports"
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --alluredir=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Resumes\reports
  inifile: None
  rootdir: E:\PYTEST_test_programs\Allure_report1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not at all familiar with the allure framework, but it sounds like you're missing the [`allure-pytest`](https://pypi.org/project/allure-pytest/) plugin which provides that command line argument

you probably need to `pip install allure-pytest` in whatever environment you're trying to run your tests in

Comment: Yes !! Your are Correct !!

Comment: @druk If the answer resolved your issue, please accept it to help other visitors. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have installed `allure-pytest` by `pip`:

```
pip list
```

If not, install it using:

```
pip install allure-pytest
```

Comment: I have installed allure-pytest, and it will also listed within "pip list", but when I check the version "allure --version", I get a message "Is not recognized as an internal.....". Do you have any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I have not encountered this problem,I suggest you use:   pip install --upgrade module_name

Answer (score -1):

for error message : ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --alluredir=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Resumes\reports
inifile: None
rootdir: E:\PYTEST_test_programs\Allure_report1
first of all enter inside of the directory where <filename.py> and run the below
.

python -m pytest <filename.py> --alluredir="report path"

python -m allure serve "report path"

Comment: This isn't very helpful; more information is needed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).